# Matching Boolean true value using jsonPath

Tags: java, json, junit, jsonpath, hamcrest

I am trying to write a JUnit test, which checks the value of received JSON. I access these values in the JSON using jsonPath. I want to check if a value is `true`. For simple jsonPaths, it works for me, but when I write more complex jsonPath query, it does not and I am getting this Assertion Error:

```
Expected: is <true>
but: was <[true]>
```

**My JSON:**

```
{...
,"trips":
  [
    {...
    ,"employee":{"name":"Ordinary Joe","login":"joe","contractor":true}
    ,...
    },
    ...
  ],
 ...
}
```

**Problematic assertion**

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.trips[?(@.employee.login=='joe')].employee.contractor", is(true)));
```

**What I've tried**

I tried to match the value also with `new Boolean(true)`, `boolean[]` array with one `true` value and after examination of `is()` matcher also with `String.valueOf(true)` however it also did not match.

**My question**

How should I correctly match this `true` value? What exactly these `[]` braces mean in the test output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the further investigation, I actually found that jsonPath somehow converts the obtained `true` value to a `JsonArray` with one item and therefore it is not possible to match it with `is(true)` matcher. I am not sure why JsonPath does so.

I found the following working workaround using `hasItem` matcher instead:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.trips[?(@.employee.login=='joe')].employee.contractor", hasItem(true)))
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.trips[?(@.employee.login=='joe')].employee.contractor", not(hasItem(false))))
```

Comment: It might return the JsonArray because it cannot ensure, that there will be only one value matching the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ==0 for true or ==1 for false

```html
{
  MyArray: [
    {
      IsTrueOrFalse: true,
      Item: "1st Item"
    },
    {
      IsTrueOrFalse: false,
      Item: "2nd Item"
    }
  ]
}
```

$..MyArray[?(@.CheckIfTrueOrFalse==0)].Item returns [ "1st Item" ]